# How do I make this code more efficient?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

The point of this code is when a user inputs into the textbox how many papers they want printed it would cost $0.30 per paper, if the user purchase more than 499 the price will change to $0.28 per paper etc. But when they check the radiobutton for ink it will cost extra $0.10 per 10 pages printed. I have figure out how to code it but its look messy.

```
  Dim paper As Decimal
Dim price As Decimal
Dim cardstock As Decimal
Dim finalprice As Decimal
Dim remainder As Decimal
Dim extra As Decimal

  Private Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn.Click, btn.Click

    paper = Val(Me.txtinput.Text)

    If noink.Checked = True Then
        If paper <= 499 Then
            price = paper * 0.3
            Me.lblprice.Text = price
        ElseIf paper <= 749 Then
            price = paper * 0.28
            Me.lblprice.Text = price
        ElseIf paper <= 999 Then
            price = paper * 0.27
            Me.lblprice.Text = price
        ElseIf price <= 1000 Then
            price = paper * 0.25
            Me.lblprice.Text = price
        End If
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub withink_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles withink.Click
    If paper <= 499 Then
        price = paper * 0.3
    ElseIf paper <= 749 Then
        price = paper * 0.28
    ElseIf paper <= 999 Then
        price = paper * 0.27
    ElseIf price <= 1000 Then
        price = paper * 0.25
    End If

    remainder = paper Mod 10
    cardstock = paper - remainder
    extra = cardstock / 100
    finalprice = extra + price
    Me.lblprice.Text = finalprice
End Sub
```

Comment: Question like this are best suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and are not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

first, try use just as checkbox instead of a radiobutton and check that checkstate, so you only need one control

second, I like the idea of having to check the textinput directly and don't use a button to check like E.Solicito suggested but thats up to your preferences

third, here's the code

```
    Private Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn.click

        If txtinput.Text.Length = 0 Then
            paper = 0
        Else
            paper = Val(Me.txtinput.Text)
        End If

        Check_Ink()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Checkbox_Status(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chb_withink.CheckedChanged
        Check_Ink()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Check_Ink()

        Select Case paper
            Case paper <= 499
                price = paper * 0.3
            Case paper <= 749
                price = paper * 0.28
            Case paper <= 999
                price = paper * 0.27
            Case Else
                price = paper * 0.25
        End Select

        If chb_withink.Checked Then

            remainder = paper Mod 10
            cardstock = paper - remainder
            extra = cardstock / 100
            price += extra

        End If

        Me.lblprice.Text = price

    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Private Sub txtinput_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtinput.TextChanged

        If txtinput.Text = Nothing Then
            txtinput.Text = 0
        End If

        paper = Val(Me.txtinput.Text)
        Check_Ink()

    End Sub
    Private Sub RadioButton_Status(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles noink.CheckedChanged, withink.CheckedChanged
        Check_Ink()
    End Sub
    Public Sub Check_Ink()

        If noink.Checked = True Then

            If paper <= 499 Then
                price = paper * 0.3
                Me.lblprice.Text = price
            ElseIf paper <= 749 Then
                price = paper * 0.28
                Me.lblprice.Text = price
            ElseIf paper <= 999 Then
                price = paper * 0.27
                Me.lblprice.Text = price
            ElseIf price <= 1000 Then
                price = paper * 0.25
                Me.lblprice.Text = price
            End If

        Else

            If paper <= 499 Then
                price = paper * 0.3
            ElseIf paper <= 749 Then
                price = paper * 0.28
            ElseIf paper <= 999 Then
                price = paper * 0.27
            ElseIf price <= 1000 Then
                price = paper * 0.25
            End If

            remainder = paper Mod 10
            cardstock = paper - remainder
            extra = cardstock / 100
            finalprice = extra + price
            Me.lblprice.Text = finalprice

        End If

    End Sub
```